# Blender not rendering specified dimensions

Tags: rendering, dimensions

I was making a channel art photo for my YouTube channel, and everything went smoothly. But when I rendered the image it wasn't the resolution that I specified.
I wanted the image to look like this:
[image: How I had the image set up]

But the rendering came out like this:
[image: It squished the sides in, warping the image]
How do I make it so it doesn't do this??

Comment: Do you have any nodes in the compositor?

Comment: Yeah I do, for the material textures

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your compositing node setup?

Comment: Your image looks squeezed because your aspect ratio is 3x2

Answer (score 3):

The stretched height comes from you having an 3:2 aspect ratio.

You would normally only want to adjust the [aspect ratio](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/video.html#pixel-aspect-ratio) when rendering video that is intended for older tv's with [non-square pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio#Issues_of_non-square_pixels).

The reason you are seeing the distortion is that the uv image editor displays images in 1:1 aspect by default, you can adjust this to match your render settings in the Display panel of the UV/Image Editors properties region <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]